# How to add rounded corner to a UIBezierPath custom rectangle?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I managed to create the rounded corners, but I'm having trouble with the first rounded corner (lower right )

Question :

- Can I add an (addArcWithCenter) method before the ( moveToPoint ) method ?
- How can i get rid of the straight line at the beginning of the rectangle (lower right) ?

here is my code for the custom rectangle and a screenshot :

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 300, y: 0))
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 300-10, y: 50), radius: 10 , startAngle: 0 , endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI/2)  , clockwise: true) //1st rounded corner
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 200, y: 50), radius:10, startAngle: CGFloat(2 * M_PI / 3), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI) , clockwise: true)// 2rd rounded corner
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 200, y: 10), radius:10, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), endAngle:CGFloat(3 * M_PI / 2), clockwise: true)// 3rd rounded corner
// little triangle at the bottom
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:240 , y:0))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 245, y: -10))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:250, y: 0))
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 290, y: 10), radius: 10, startAngle: CGFloat(3 * M_PI / 2), endAngle: CGFloat(2 * M_PI ), clockwise: true)
path.closePath()
```

[image]

Comment: So what's the rest?You actually get the similar effect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of starting the code with a straight line :

```
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 300, y: 0))
```

I instead start with an arc (upper right):

```
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 300-10, y: 50), radius: 10 , startAngle: 0 , endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI/2)  , clockwise: true) //1st rounded corner
```

and by doing this, I have four rounded corners and I just need to add a straight line at the end of the code right before:

```
path.closePath()
```

Here is the code and a screenshot:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 300-10, y: 50), radius: 10 , startAngle: 0 , endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI/2)  , clockwise: true) //1st rounded corner
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 200, y: 50), radius:10, startAngle: CGFloat(2 * M_PI / 3), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI) , clockwise: true)// 2rd rounded corner
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 200, y: 10), radius:10, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), endAngle:CGFloat(3 * M_PI / 2), clockwise: true)// 3rd rounded corner
// little triangle
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:240 , y:0))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 245, y: -10))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:250, y: 0))
path.addArcWithCenter(CGPoint(x: 290, y: 10), radius: 10, startAngle: CGFloat(3 * M_PI / 2), endAngle: CGFloat(2 * M_PI ), clockwise: true)
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:300 , y:50))
path.closePath()
```

[image]

Comment: Glad you found it. This is actually what I was describing. :D

Comment: To improve this you should take the radius and height and width out into variables. That way you can make the bubble any size and have any corner radius just by changing one value.

Comment: Should I put the x and y in variables ? But they are different from one line of code to the other. Could you explain more? Thanks

Comment: ah. Well I'd actually draw this on a separate UIView that can be positioned independently. Then the position of the bubble will start at (0, 0). In this case though your x y values are a function of the position of the bubble and the size of it. Bottom right corner is (x + width, y + height) and so on.

Answer (score 25):

I think what you're doing is overly complicated. UIBezierPath gives you `UIBezierPath(roundedRect:)` so why not use it? Stroke the rounded rectangle; erase the spot where you're going to put the little triangle; add the triangle; fill the compound path; and stroke the missing two sides of the triangle. Like this (this is just some code I happened to have lying around - you should change the numbers to fit your shape, of course):

```
let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
CGContextTranslateCTM(con, 10, 10)
UIColor.blueColor().setStroke()
UIColor.blueColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.4).setFill()
let p = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0,0,250,180), cornerRadius: 10)
p.stroke()
CGContextClearRect(con, CGRectMake(20,170,10,11))
let pts = [
    CGPointMake(20,180), CGPointMake(20,200),
    CGPointMake(20,200), CGPointMake(30,180)
]
p.moveToPoint(pts[0])
p.addLineToPoint(pts[1])
p.addLineToPoint(pts[3])
p.fill()
CGContextStrokeLineSegments(con, pts, 4)
```

[image]

Comment: A very good reason for not using it would be if you are planning on doing "strokeStart" and "strokeEnd" animations. In that case it matters "where" the rect starts drawing its line. When using a path, you have control over that.

Answer (score 18):

A couple of observations:

1. Make sure that you take the view `bounds` and inset it by half of the line width. That ensures that the entire stroked border falls within the `bounds` of the view. If your line width is 1, this might not be so obvious, but with larger line widths, the problem becomes more pronounced.
2. If using `draw(_:)` method, don’t use the `rect` that is passed to this method, but rather refer to the `bounds` (inset, as described above). The `CGRect` passed to `draw(_:)` is the rectangle being drawn, not necessarily the full `bounds`. (It generally is, but not always, so always refer to the `bounds` of the view, not the `rect` passed to this method.)

   As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw) says (emphasis added):

   > The portion of the view’s bounds that needs to be updated. The first time your view is drawn, this rectangle is typically the entire visible bounds of your view. *However, during subsequent drawing operations, the rectangle may specify only part of your view.*
3. I’d give all of the the various properties of the view a `didSet` observer that will trigger the view to be redrawn. That way, any IB overrides or programmatically set values will be reflected in the resulting view automatically.
4. If you want, you can make the whole thing `@IBDesignable` and make the properties `@IBInspectable`, so you can see this rendered in Interface Builder. It’s not necessary, but can be useful if you want to see this rendered in storyboards or NIBs.
5. While you can round corners using a circular arc, using a quad curve is easier, IMHO. You just specify where the arc ends and the corner of the rectangle, and the quadratic bezier will produce a nicely rounded corner. Using this technique, no calculation of angles or the center of the arc is necessary.

Thus:

```swift
@IBDesignable
public class BubbleView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable public var lineWidth:      CGFloat = 1                           { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius:   CGFloat = 10                          { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable public var calloutSize:    CGSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 5) { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable public var fillColor:      UIColor = .yellow                     { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }
    @IBInspectable public var strokeColor:    UIColor = .black                      { didSet { setNeedsDisplay() } }

    override public func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let rect = bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth / 2, dy: lineWidth / 2)
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        // lower left corner
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + cornerRadius, y: rect.maxY - calloutSize.height))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY - calloutSize.height - cornerRadius),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY - calloutSize.height))

        // left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY + cornerRadius))

        // upper left corner
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + cornerRadius, y: rect.minY),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))

        // top
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - cornerRadius, y: rect.minY))

        // upper right corner
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + cornerRadius),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))

        // right
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY - calloutSize.height - cornerRadius))

        // lower right corner
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - cornerRadius, y: rect.maxY - calloutSize.height),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY - calloutSize.height))

        // bottom (including callout)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + calloutSize.width / 2, y: rect.maxY - calloutSize.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - calloutSize.width / 2, y: rect.maxY - calloutSize.height))
        path.close()

        fillColor.setFill()
        path.fill()

        strokeColor.setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = lineWidth
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

That yields:

[image]

Comment: Wow! It's really good answer! I've tried to figure out the way to solve my problem to set corner with UIBezierPath and I got what I want by myself. But If I could find this answer I think I can get the answer faster! Good!!

Comment: @rob what is calloutSize used for?

Comment: @Shubhendu - It is the size of the little callout pointer at the bottom of the bubble. I've updated it to be a `CGSize`.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me to solve a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5** with configuration variables:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let arrowXOffset: CGFloat = 13
    let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 6
    let arrowHeight: CGFloat = 6

    let mainRect = CGRect(origin: rect.origin, size: CGSize(width: rect.width, height: rect.height - arrowHeight))

    let leftTopPoint = mainRect.origin
    let rightTopPoint = CGPoint(x: mainRect.maxX, y: mainRect.minY)
    let rightBottomPoint = CGPoint(x: mainRect.maxX, y: mainRect.maxY)
    let leftBottomPoint = CGPoint(x: mainRect.minX, y: mainRect.maxY)

    let leftArrowPoint = CGPoint(x: leftBottomPoint.x + arrowXOffset, y: leftBottomPoint.y)
    let centerArrowPoint = CGPoint(x: leftArrowPoint.x + arrowHeight, y: leftArrowPoint.y + arrowHeight)
    let rightArrowPoint = CGPoint(x: leftArrowPoint.x + 2 * arrowHeight, y: leftArrowPoint.y)

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rightTopPoint.x - cornerRadius, y: rightTopPoint.y + cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius,
                startAngle: CGFloat(3 * Double.pi / 2), endAngle: CGFloat(2 * Double.pi), clockwise: true)
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rightBottomPoint.x - cornerRadius, y: rightBottomPoint.y - cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius,
                startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2), clockwise: true)

    path.addLine(to: rightArrowPoint)
    path.addLine(to: centerArrowPoint)
    path.addLine(to: leftArrowPoint)

    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: leftBottomPoint.x + cornerRadius, y: leftBottomPoint.y - cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius,
                startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), clockwise: true)
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: leftTopPoint.x + cornerRadius, y: leftTopPoint.y + cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius,
                startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), endAngle: CGFloat(3 * Double.pi / 2), clockwise: true)


    path.addLine(to: rightTopPoint)
    path.close()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You can simply use CGFloat.pi instead of CGFloat(Double.pi)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this automatically. You have to make the lines shorter and then use arcs of the radius that you want the corner radius to be.

So. Instead of adding a line to x,y you add the line to x-radius, y.
Then add the arc. Then the next line starts at x, y+radius.

Comment: @AziCode I can tomorrow. It's 1:30am now though. :-)