# Swift -Combine 2 UIViews with 1 Seamless Border

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have the following 2 UIViews pinned together.

[image]

The top is regular UIView named **ballonView** and the bottom is a subclass of UIView name **TriangleView**. I have a `border` going around the ballonView but I want the `border` to also go around the triangleView like this. The border appears seamless.

[image]

How can I do this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .black

    displayBalloonView()
}

lazy var balloonView: UIView = {
    let v = UIView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .orange
    v.layer.borderWidth = 3
    v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    v.layer.masksToBounds = true
    v.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner, .layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    return v
}()

lazy var triangleView: TriangleView = {
    let v = TriangleView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.fillColor = UIColor.orange
    v.backgroundColor = .clear
    return v
}()


func displayBalloonView() {

    view.addSubview(balloonView)
    balloonView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    balloonView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    balloonView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
    balloonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true
    
    view.addSubview(triangleView)
    triangleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: balloonView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    triangleView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: balloonView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    triangleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
    triangleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
    
    let messageLabel = UILabel()
    messageLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    messageLabel.text = "Tap here to see more"
    messageLabel.textColor = .white
    messageLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .medium)
    messageLabel.textAlignment = .center
    messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0 // the text might be more than 1 line and I would set the balloonView to the label's height but for simplicity I just set the ballonView heightConstraint to 70
    messageLabel.sizeToFit()
    
    balloonView.addSubview(messageLabel)
    messageLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: balloonView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    messageLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: balloonView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
    messageLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: balloonView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
}
```

TriangleView:

```
class TriangleView : UIView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    var fillColor = UIColor()
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: (rect.midX), y: rect.maxY))
        context.closePath()
        context.setFillColor(fillColor.cgColor)
        context.fillPath()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: use single shape layer in single view

Comment: you mean combine the triangle and balloonView into 1 view?

Comment: As SPatel said, yes, just make a single bezier path that looks the way you want (balloon plus arrow) and draw it yourself. You can fill it and stroke it and it will look just the way you want.

Comment: @matt ok thanks, I’ll try it in the morning, about to fall asleep. It’s late here

Comment: Although it would be handy if there was a way to "union" views...

Comment: @SPatel thanks I'll try it in the morning

Comment: You can "union" _paths_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply draw the rounded-rectangle-with-triangle shape "by hand" as a bezier path. I ended up with this as a sketch:

[image]

Putting a label in front of it is left as an exercise for the reader. It's just an image view containing an image that I constructed in code:

```
let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 100))
let im = r.image {
    ctx in
    let con = ctx.cgContext
    con.move(to: CGPoint(x:100, y:10))
    con.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x:190, y:10), tangent2End: CGPoint(x:190, y:80), radius: 10)
    con.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x:190, y:80), tangent2End: CGPoint(x:0, y:80), radius: 10)
    con.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:110, y:80))
    con.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:100, y:95))
    con.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:90, y:80))
    con.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x:10, y:80), tangent2End: CGPoint(x:10, y:0), radius: 10)
    con.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x:10, y:10), tangent2End: CGPoint(x:200, y:10), radius: 10)
    con.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:100, y:10))
    con.setLineWidth(3)
    con.setStrokeColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    con.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
    con.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
}
let iv = UIImageView(image:im)
```

You add the image view to your interface and put the label in front of it and you're all set. Of course I've hard-coded my numbers but hey, it's only a sketch; tweak as desired.

Comment: why didn't you link to your answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31216610/4833705? I haven't tried it yet but it seems like that would work too

Comment: I don't think that approach is as good. There are lots of answers about how to union two shapes, or to give the appearance of doing so; researching that is _your_ job, not mine.