# How to use lineJoin and lineJoinStyle with a UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have a mask applied to a view using `CAShapeLayer` and `UIBezierPath`. I'd like to add a rounding effect to the line joins but it's not working. How do I round the corners of this shape?

You can plug the following into an Xcode playground.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

private class ProfileImageView: UIView {
    private let imageView = UIImageView()
    var image: UIImage?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let h = rect.height
        let w = rect.width
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w-32, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: 32))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: h))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 32, y: h))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: h-32))
        path.close()
        path.lineJoinStyle = .round
        shapeLayer.lineJoin = .round
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = shapeLayer
        imageView.image = image
    }
}

class VC: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .gray
        
        let imgView = ProfileImageView()
        imgView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(imgView)
        imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -64).isActive = true
        imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -64).isActive = true
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = VC()
```

Comment: You might find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214620/how-to-add-rounded-corner-to-a-uibezierpath-custom-rectangle

Comment: *"How do I round the corners of this shape?"* -- we need to see the result you are trying to get. Right now, your shape has 6 corners.... Which ones do you want "round"? How do you *want* it to look?

Comment: @DonMag I want all of them rounded.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question... Rounded by how much? In this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxWkY.png  - your current path looks like the top one... do you want it to look like the bottom one? Or something else?

Comment: @DonMag well, if they can be rounded then hopefully I can adjust by how much but if not then I will still take it. I don't want to lose any joints. Rounding corners (maybe this is just a graphic-design term and I should have been more clear) just means rounding the point where two segments of the same line join to change direction. In your example, the shape has lost 2 of its joints and now has 4 corners, no longer 6.

Comment: This is why I said ***"we need to see the result you are trying to get"*** -- grab your favorite graphics program and draw how you ***want*** it to look - then update your question with the image(s). Trying to guess is just a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

`lineJoinStyle` is only for stroked paths. Since yours is a mask, you need a filled path instead so I think you'll need to use `path.addCurve` to achieve rounded corners in your mask. Or depending on your shape and size you may be able to just apply `lineWidth`, `strokeColor` and `lineJoinStyle` to your `CAShapeLayer` and get the rounded effect you're looking for.

Comment: That makes sense to me, let me try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Still trying to guess at your goal, but maybe this is what you're looking for?

[image]

```
private class ProfileImageView: UIImageView {

    public var cornerRadius: Double = 16 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    public var angleRadius: Double = 24 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    public var angleIndent: CGFloat = 32 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    private func commonInit() {
        contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        layer.mask = shapeLayer
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let rect = bounds
        
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.midY))
        
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY),
                    tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY),
                    radius: cornerRadius)
        
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - angleIndent, y: rect.minY),
                    tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + angleIndent),
                    radius: angleRadius)
        
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + angleIndent),
                    tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY),
                    radius: angleRadius)
        
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY),
                    tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY),
                    radius: cornerRadius)
        
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + angleIndent, y: rect.maxY),
                    tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY - angleIndent),
                    radius: angleRadius)
        
        path.addArc(tangent1End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY - angleIndent),
                    tangent2End: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY),
                    radius: angleRadius)
        
        path.closeSubpath()
        
        shapeLayer.path = path
    }
    
}

class VC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

        guard let img = UIImage(named: "sampleImage") else {
            fatalError("Could not load sample image!!")
        }

        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.spacing = 20
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        let imgView1 = ProfileImageView(frame: .zero)
        imgView1.image = img
        
        let imgView2 = ProfileImageView(frame: .zero)
        imgView2.image = img

        // top view uses default properties,
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imgView1)

        // slightly different properties for the bottom view
        imgView2.cornerRadius = 24
        imgView2.angleRadius = 32
        imgView2.angleIndent = 48

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(imgView2)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.widthAnchor, constant: -100.0),
            
            imgView1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView1.widthAnchor),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```