How to Create a Custom Shape with a Button in the Bottom-Right Corner of a UIView in iOS?
I am trying to create a custom shape that appears at the bottom-right corner of a UIView. The shape could be a triangle or any other geometric figure, and it should also include a button positioned at the corner. Here's what I need help with:
Drawing a custom shape using UIBezierPath or CAShapeLayer.
Ensuring the button is properly placed within or overlapping the shape.
What I have tried:
I explored using UIBezierPath to draw shapes but struggled to position it correctly.
I am not sure how to integrate the button into the shape.
Could someone provide an example or guide me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated.


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can try this view, insetRight is width of cut out space by orange circle:
class CustomView: UIView {
    
    var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 8.0
    var fillColor: UIColor = .red
    var insetRight: CGFloat = 20

    override public func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let rect = bounds
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        // lower left corner
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + cornerRadius, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY - cornerRadius),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))

        // left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY + cornerRadius))

        // upper left corner
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + cornerRadius, y: rect.minY),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))

        // top
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - cornerRadius, y: rect.minY))

        // upper right corner
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY + cornerRadius),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))

        // right
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY - cornerRadius - insetRight))

        // lower right corner
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - cornerRadius, y: rect.maxY - insetRight),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY - insetRight))
        
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - insetRight + cornerRadius, y: rect.maxY - insetRight))
        
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - insetRight, y: rect.maxY - insetRight + cornerRadius),
                          controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - insetRight, y: rect.maxY - insetRight))
        
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - insetRight, y: rect.maxY - cornerRadius))
        path.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - insetRight - cornerRadius, y: rect.maxY), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - insetRight, y: rect.maxY))

        path.close()

        fillColor.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}



Just go around google to see people draw some example shape, then you can try on your own, here my code is base on this excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214620/how-to-add-rounded-corner-to-a-uibezierpath-custom-rectangle
